Canon Pixma ix-6550 Driver with Ubuntu 24.04
I have operated a Canon ix6550 printer under many Ubuntu versions very successfully. I recently updated to Ubuntu 24.04 and now cannot print. The Canon database no longer provides a driver in the Ubuntu printer setup. The only driver available from the Canon site cannot be installed because of unavailable supporting packages. The Canon site says that the printer is obsolete and is no longer supported. Is there a work-around or is there a 3rd party driver?
